# JQuery UI autocomplete, Load all Data in DOM instead taking from mysql DB

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Reason: Want to speedup autocoplete result

What i have: I am having two Input boxes. One is Category and another one is Variety. First im selecting Category by,

```
$("#category").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("./php/autocompletenontex_getcategory.php", { category: request.term }, response);
    },
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#variety').focus();
    }
}).focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});
```

The above code shows autocomplete result before start typing.

My PHP Code is:
//after including DB connection

```
$category =  $_REQUEST["category"];
    $sql = "SELECT distinct(category) FROM master_nontextile WHERE category LIKE '%".$category."%'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $results[] = array('label' => $row['category'], 'value' => $row['category']);
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
```

The next Input Field is Variety - variety autocomplete result is based on category's selection. The Code is below

```
$("#variety").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("./php/autocompletenontex_getvariety.php", { variety: request.term, category: $("#category").val() }, response);
    },
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#variety').val(ui.item.variety);
        $('#price').val(ui.item.price);
        $('#quantity').focus();
    }
}).focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});
```

Corresponding PHP is:

```
//after including DB connection
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT variety, price FROM master_nontextile WHERE category = '$category' AND ( variety LIKE '%".$variety."%' OR price ='$variety' ) ORDER BY variety ASC"); $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $results[] = array('label' => $row['variety'].' - '.$row['price'], 'value' => $row['variety'], 'price' => $row['price']);
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
```

Problem:
We have a billing application. In variety field they can type a variety name or price. **While typing the autocomplete result shows the result after 1 second** (Client is feeling this is tooooo late).
So i need it to populate fast on typing price or variety name.
i think it is taking time to make connection then retireving is taking time.

I came to know we can load datas on page load by using ajax request [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492475/speeding-up-jquery-autocomplete-unavoidably-long-lists)
This solution is ok for one independent autocomplete field. But im having two input field, the second one's result is depends on first one. so how can i achieve it without going to DB?

Comment: ah! im waiting for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are getting data slower than you expect. You are limited by the speed at which your database returns the results. I can suggest you following to speed up.

1. Dont make a new connection to mysql from php for every request. Enable database connection pooling. It improves performance quite a lot. I dont know how to do connection pool in php. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830707/php-connection-pooling-mysql) might help.
2. If possible cache the results in php, so that you dont hit the db everytime.
3. Use an external service to serve data for autocomplete. Look at [Autocomplete as a Service](http://aaas.io)

Comment: Love u buddy! This single line solved my problem (my app runs in local only)
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));